# Can is see differences in my pycharm configuration settings versus the defaults?

Tags: configuration, pycharm

Pycharm 2.7.3 on Ubuntu raring.

I've made several configuration changes to my pycharm installation and to various projects. Is there a way to have pycharm report what I've changed versus the default installation?